# Умножение на двойное слово

Tags: ассемблер, masm

После выполнения команды `mul ebx` я получаю произведение в `edx:eax`. Заношу в стек это произведение: `push edx`, `push eax`. Через некоторое время понадобилось умножить *текущий* `edx:eax` на произведение в стеке. Вопрос, как это сделать? Если просто написать `mul [esp]`, то, я так понимаю, результат будет неправильный...

Comment: В смысле, Вы хотите умножить 64 бита на 64 через 32-х битовое умножение?

Comment: А 64 битные регистры rax, rdx не доступны ? И вы же понимаете что при умножении edx:eax на 64 битное значение результат может быть 128 бит, т.е. для хранения результата потребуется 4 регистра по 32 бита. Так что умножать частями и складывать

Comment: но ведь edx:eax - это 64 бита, в стеке у вас лежит еще 64 бита, таким образом результат запросто превысит 64 бита

Comment: @Zealint умножить 64 на 64 с помощью `mul`

Comment: @kor с помощью `mul` не получится умножить 64 бита на 64, потому что в результате получите 128 бит ответа. Если вас не волнует переполнение, то нужно просто умножить младшие 32 бита одного множителя и младшие 32 бита другого. Но результат будет неправильный. В результате будут правильными только младшие 32 бита результата из 128-ми.

Comment: Можно, конечно, разбивать число на части и с помощью нескольких сложений и умножений получить что нужно, но это довольно непросто. Нужно имитировать умножение в столбик.

Comment: @Zealint а если два 64-битных гарантированно в произведении не превышают 64 бита?

Comment: @kor произведение двух 64 битных не превышает 64 бита тогда и только тогда, когда у обоих чисел старшие 32 бита равны нулю, т.е. по сути у вас два 32 битных числа :)

Comment: @Mike, Вы не правы. Первое число может иметь 64 бита, а второе 1.

Comment: @Zealint Да, согласен.

Comment: @kor, тогда нужно умножать в столбик, но придётся выполнять 4 умножения и несколько сложений. Это будет довольно длинный код.

Comment: @kor Я написал начало ответа. Сейчас могу продолжить и написать дальше уже на asm. Но уже из текущего ответа видно, какие части результата уйдут в переполнение, это очень большое "переполнение"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы хотите умножить 2 числа по 64 бита с помощью 32 битных операций. Давайте для начала представим это в десятичной системе и пусть 32 бита это один десятичный разряд:

54*68=5*6*100 + 5*8*10 + 4*6*10 + 4*8

Умножения на 10 и 100 отлично показывают в каком слове у вас должны оказаться результирующие разряды.

Пожалуй мы не будем выбрасывать переполнение, а напишем умножение с получением 128 битного результата с сохранением его в памяти. Если старшая часть по каким то причинам не нужна - можете ее не использовать и не сохранять. Умножение самых старших частей тогда можно не делать.

```
res0  DD  0   ; 0-31  биты результата
res1  DD  0   ; 32-63 биты
res2  DD  0   ; 64-95 биты
res3  DD  0   ; 96-127 биты
...
;edx:eax  - первый множитель X
;ebx:ecx  - второй множитель Y
push  edx      ; Оставим старшую часть первого множителя пока в покое
push  eax      ; Младшую копируем на будущее
mul   ecx      ; Младшая часть X * Младшую Y
mov   res0, eax
mov   res1, edx; Сохраняем
pop   eax      ; Восстановили младшую X
mul   ebx      ; Младшая X * Старшую Y
add   res1, eax
adc   res2, edx; В res2 старшая часть результата + флаг переноса при сложении в младшей
pop   eax      ; Старшую часть X в EAX
push  eax      ; И сохраняем опять на будущее
mul   ecx      ; Старшая X * Младшую Y
add   res1, eax
adc   res2, edx; Вот тут опять может возникнуть перенос
adc   res3, 0  ; Который мы сохраняем в самую старшую часть результата
pop   eax      ; Восстановили старшую X
mul   ebx      ; Перемножаем старшие части
add   res2, eax
adc   res3, edx
```

Вот как то так, 100% гарантии дать не могу, проверять не на чем

Answer (score 0):

С учётом комментариев к вопросу, делаем так.

Умножаем младшие 32 бита первого множителя на младшие 32 бита второго. 
Затем умножаем младшие 32 бита первого множителя на старшие 32 бита второго. И младшую часть результата прибавляем к старшей половине предыдущего умножения. 
Теперь симметрично: старшие 32 бита первого на младшие 32 бита второго. Добавляем младшие 32 бита результата к старшим 32-м битам первого умножения.

Получается 3 умножения и 2 сложения. Если кратко, то это выглядит так:

```
    a b
    c d
-------
     bd
    ad  
    bc
```